Detect and mount device
Ubuntu can't mount one of my flashes.
Output of some commands are listed,
kami@kami:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2829
loop2    7:2    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1380
loop3    7:3    0  66.2M  1 loop /snap/core24/423
loop4    7:4    0 269.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4173
loop5    7:5    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop6    7:6    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
loop7    7:7    0 268.7M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4483
loop8    7:8    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop9    7:9    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop10   7:10   0 177.2M  1 loop /snap/skype/348
loop11   7:11   0  10.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1124
loop12   7:12   0  10.4M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1147
loop13   7:13   0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop14   7:14   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop15   7:15   0   476K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop16   7:16   0 138.9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/490
loop17   7:17   0 138.9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/482
sda      8:0    0 233.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 112.6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                /
├─sda3   8:3    0 119.2G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0   977M  0 part 

"dmesg" command output:
[  985.817120] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  985.943830] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=abcd, idProduct=1234, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  985.943839] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  985.943843] usb 1-2: Product: UDisk           
[  985.943845] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: General 
[  985.943847] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: Љ
[  985.965634] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  985.965800] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[  985.965917] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  985.968943] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 1007.823819] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
kami@kami:~$ 

kami@kami:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1737:0077 802.11g Adapter [Linksys WUSB54GC v3] WUSB54GC v3 802.11g Adapter [Ralink RT2070L]
Bus 001 Device 008: ID abcd:1234 LogiLink UDisk flash drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

No, It was not used on any Windows system,though used on MacOS. I did use it as an installer for Ubuntu before....I see a strange character as "SerialNumber" shown at output of "dmesg" command....any clue?

Your dmesg output shows that your usb device is detected. Could just be permissions issue. Try sudo lsusb. You could also try restarting the system.
What do you mean by "same issue"? Also, share info like what filesystem the usb has, does it contain only data, etc?
As a side note, you can format the command outputs (you have options in the same edit window).

kami@kami:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1737:0077 802.11g Adapter [Linksys WUSB54GC v3] WUSB54GC v3 802.11g Adapter [Ralink RT2070L]
Bus 001 Device 008: ID abcd:1234 LogiLink UDisk flash drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

It's detected,but can't be mounted....any suggestion?....it contains only data, about filesystem I don't know.

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Was the USB key in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to t7urn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
